# C++ Assignment strange behaviour

Tags: c++, variable-assignment, copy-constructor

Could you explain me the output of the following code? The variable changes it's value at the end of assignment.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

using namespace std;

template<class CRTP>
class object_t {
public:
    object_t<CRTP> &operator=(const object_t<CRTP> &a) {
        ((CRTP*)this)->~CRTP();
        new ((CRTP*)this) CRTP(*(const CRTP*)&a);
        cout << "Value in assignment: " << ((CRTP*)this)->n << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

class darr_t : public object_t<darr_t> {
public:

    int n;

    darr_t(const darr_t &a) : n(a.n + 1) {
       cout << "Value in constructor: " << n << endl;  
    }

    darr_t(int pn) : n(pn) {}
};

int main() {

    darr_t tmp(42);
    darr_t tmp2(55);
    tmp = tmp2;

    cout << "Value in main: " << tmp.n << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Value in constructor: 56
>   Value in assignment: 56
>   Value in main: 55

Expected output:

> Value in constructor: 56
>   Value in assignment: 56
>   Value in main: 56

Edit:
Thanks to @Cheersandhth.-Alf and @Mr_Hic-up answers!
The problem is that default darr_t::operator= first calls base type's assignment but after that it calls assignment(overrides) for members of darr_t object!

Comment: what's the purpose of the code. perhaps we can suggest better ways to do whatever it is.

Comment: re the result: You're using the default darr_t::operator=. It doesn't do anything fancy. Hence you get non-fancy result. This looks like homework. I can't for the life of me imagine that anyone would write code like this. Just about everything's wrong with it. If it's not homework then, please, DO NOT do things like that. At least not in code that others have to maintain.

Comment: It is not safe to manually call the destructor. If there is an exception in the new operator in the next line, the object is in an undefined state.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Default darr_t::operator= uses object_t<CRTP>::operator=. The problem is that inside object_t<CRTP>::operator= we set n to 56 then we output this n and get 56. But after execution of this function n becomes 55.

Comment: @Barricadenick: read up on what a generated assignment operator does. try to generate it by hand, as the compiler would do. see if that helps you understand this?

Comment: The "operator =" is not inherited by the sub-class. That's part of the C++ standard. The fact that the "object_t" assignment operator code is executed is a bit weird. The way I understand it the compiler simply calls the assignment operator of the base class and then executes the current class operator. But as Cheers and hth - Alf mentions, the compiler generates one that will blindly copy the attributes. So this is probably why the value is then brought back to "55".

Comment: Note: `*(const CRTP*)&a` should be `static_cast<CRTP const&>(a)` and you should be able to call `new (this) CRTP(...);` without casting `this` to anything as placement `new` takes a `void*` anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You are observing the behavior because:

1. The compiler defines an implicit copy assignment operator for `darr_t`.
2. The implicit copy assignment calls the copy assignment operator of the base class first before performing copy assignment of the member variables.

Here's relevant documentation from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_operator:

> **Implicitly-declared copy assignment operator**
>
> If no user-defined copy assignment operators are provided for a class type (`struct`, `class`, or `union`), the compiler will always declare one as an inline public member of the class. This implicitly-declared copy assignment operator has the form `T& T::operator=(const T&)` if all of the following is true:
>
> each direct base `B` of `T` has a copy assignment operator whose parameters are `B` or `const B&` or `const volatile B&`
>
> each non-static data member `M` of `T` of class type or array of class type has a copy assignment operator whose parameters are `M` or `const M&` or `const volatile M&`
>
> Otherwise the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator is declared as `T& T::operator=(T&)`. (Note that due to these rules, the implicitly-declared copy assignment operator cannot bind to a volatile lvalue argument)

Answer (score 0):

```
    new ((CRTP*)this) CRTP(*(const CRTP*)&a);
```

That pointer magic you're trying to pull isn't doing what you expect it to.  Adding some lines to print out the addresses of the object before printing the variable yields (on my machine):

```
Address in constructor: 0x7fff56264610
Value in constructor: 56
Address in assignment: 0x7fff56264610
Value in assignment: 56
Address in main: 0x7fff56264618
Value in main: 55
```